PDF Fields from PDFbox not printing on mobile (Android generic pdf viewer problem)
I generate a pdf with pdfbox and set some fields.  The downloaded pdf is missing the fields in print preview and are not printed in the default pdf viewers of ios and android but if I install adobe acrobat they are properly shown and printed.
PDF displays correctly and prints on in chrome on my macbook
First I thought that the font wasn't supported so I removed the helvetica and made it use the embedded font using.
 pDAcroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);.  This removed the not embedded font
Template is retrieved
 public byte[] createPdf(long customer, UUID id, int amount) throws xxxxxxx {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream;
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:xxxxxx.pdf");
        try (PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(resource.getFile());) {
            PDAcroForm pDAcroForm = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
            pDAcroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);

fields are edited with
 PDTextField fieldCustomer = (PDTextField) pDAcroForm.getField("customer");
            fieldCustomer.setValue(String.valueOf(customerId));
            fieldCustomer.setReadOnly(true);
....
    outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            pdDocument.save(outputStream);

-------- SOLUTION/WORKAROUND-----------
It seems that basic android pdf viewers do not support fillable form fields.  Users must open it in a real pdf app like adobe to use fields.  I have replaced the fields that I supply the input for with normal text lines. in case you're also enjoying this suprise see this snippet. `
 ``` PDPage firstPage=pdDocument.getPage(0);
            PDFont pdfFont= PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
            int fontSize = 14;
        

            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, firstPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND,true,true);
            contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(210,500);
            contentStream.showText(xxxxx);
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0,-28);
            contentStream.showText(xxxxx);
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0,-28);
            contentStream.showText(fxxxxxx);
            contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.close();```


please try the same with PDFBox for desktop and see if it works then. Also share the file when done with Android, I could then tell if there is a flaw in the PDF.

pdf belongs to my customer, I dont have control over it and it's top secret but thanks for your interest.

Try the same with a not secret PDF to see if the effect happens, e.g. a state tax form. Or with the PDF created by the desktop PDFBox project: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateSimpleForm.java?revision=1881001&view=markup

"pDAcroForm.setNeedAppearances(true)" - Generally I would recommend against doing this because this makes the resulting PDF signal to the recipient PDF viewer that all the appearances of all the fields need to be regenerated and it tells PDFBox that it doesn't need to care about appearances.

A PDF may have "Form Fields" (even of many types).
However it is not considered mandatory for a PDF reader to allow their use (only display their basic appearances.)
This is common for the faster lighter weight readers found in desktop or mobile web browsing.
Take for example this secured modern browser. There are 3 alternate PDF viewers. The fastest "shows" binary field content only and the slowest uses Acrobats own less secured plugin. The middleweight is variable and JS based but not a true PDF binary render engine.


